# List Index csv file on different lines

Tags: python, csv, indexing

Is it possible to split each index in a list on to a new row when writing to a csv?

For example, I append a number of indexes to a list and when I write to csv, they all print on the same row.

Current output from route.append when I write to a csv file is...

```
("Index1")("Index2")("Index3")("Index4")("Index5")("Index6")
```

I would like to write it as:

```
("Index1")
("Index2")
("Index3")
("Index4")
("Index5")
("Index6")
```

I know I can write

```
rec=index[1]
f.writerow(rec)
```

and repeat 6 times.. the problem is, I can have anything from 2 indexes to 100 indexes in my list so what I need to do is be able to print n number of indexes based on the amount of indexes in the list.

Thanks.
    f=open("route1.csv","w")
    f.truncate()
    f.close()

```
print "Route Calculator"
cur = (0, 0)
route = [0]
xy = [ ]
z= ()
zz= []
dest=[]
n = input("Enter number of destinations to visit:")
a = range(1, n + 1)
cidd = []
for i in range(n):
    cid=raw_input("Enter Customer ID")
    f3=csv.reader(open("data/customer.csv",'r'))
    for row in f3:
        if row[0]==cid:
            street=row[2]
            pcode=row[3]
            tel=row[4]
            x=eval(row[5])
            y=eval(row[6])
            z=row[1]
            xy.append((x,y))
            zz.append(((cid,z)))
            cidd.append((((cid,z,street,pcode,tel))))

print "Destinations:",cidd
dest = [ ]
ndd =[ ]
for i in range(n):
    nd = []
    for i in xy:
        i = list(i)
        distance = round(math.hypot((cur[0] - i[0]), (cur[1] - i[1])),4)
        nd.append(distance)

    print "Current location:", cur
    print "Coordinates to travel to:", xy
    print "Distances to destinations:", nd, "minimum distance:", min(nd)
    nn = (xy[nd.index(min(nd))][0], xy[nd.index(min(nd))][1])
    print "Nearest neighbour:", nn
    print "Nearest destination:", cidd[xy.index(nn)]
    print
    dest.append(((min(nd))))
    ndd=sum(dest)
    route.append(((cidd[xy.index(nn)],(min(nd)))))
    del cidd[xy.index(nn)]
    xy.remove(nn)
    cur = list(nn)

distance = round(math.hypot(nn[0], nn[1]), 4)
dest.append(distance)
route.append(0)
cidd.extend(dest)
print "Destination List:",route
o=open("route1.csv",'ab')
f=csv.writer(o)
rec3=("Driver:",driver)
f.writerow(rec3)
rec4=("Date:",(time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")))
f.writerow(rec4)
header=(["CID..","Customer Name..........","Address.........","Postcode..","Telephone..","Distance from prev"])
f.writerow(header)
rec=(route)
f.writerow(rec)
rectotal=("Total Distance to Travel",ndd)
f.writerow(rectotal)
print "Route Saved to route1.csv"
```

This is my current code and its the route.append im trying to index onto separate lines. thanks

Comment: Please provide full code that generates the undesirable output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the following works

```
rec=(route[1],)
f.writerow(rec)
```

You can just use a `for` loop to avoid writing it multiple times.

```
for i in xrange(len(index)):
    rec=(route[i],) 
    f.writerow(rec)
```

Comment: Sorry I should have worded this clearer. rec=(route[1]) is what works.. would the same still apply? Thanks

Comment: @user3472009 If you are just indexing and printing, it should work with the appropriate modification.

Comment: I tried this method but i keep getting   File "E:\HNC Computing\Unit 18 Procedural Programming\18-02\Assignment\newprogram1.py", line 96, in newroute
    f.writerow(rec)
Error: sequence expected  any ideas? thanks

Comment: @user3472009, See my update and notice the extra `,` after `route[i]`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've spent hours on this but now it works perfectly.. Very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

just use `writerows` function.

example:

```
f.writerows(["a","b","c"])
```

will output

```
a
b
c
```